# Xubuntu lock screen appearing twice

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xfce, lock-screen, light-locker

I'm running Xubuntu 15.10. When I leave my machine for an extended period of time, I return to find the screen locked by `light-locker`.

I can then enter my password, and it is accepted, but then the lock screen is displayed a second time! Once I enter my password on this second lock screen, I'm returned to my desktop session.

I don't know enough about `light-dm`/`light-locker` and friends to know where the issue is. Can anyone help?

Comment: This bug has been reported at https://github.com/the-cavalry/light-locker/issues/118

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want `light-locker`, you can safely remove it using:

```
sudo apt remove light-locker
```

and Xfce will use only its own locker.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

- Go to *Settings → Screensaver* and turn off all switches.
- Then go to *Settings → Screensaver → Lockscreen* and turn off all switches.

**Cause**

This must be happening because LightDM and your default screensaver are conflicting with each other. So turning off all your screensaver settings enables only the LightDM greeter to show in lock screen.

The above worked for me.